# how to build a summary table with different counts on col

Tags: r

I have a df that looks like this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

It can be build using codes:

```
structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Pass = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    Math = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1), ELA = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0), PE = c(0, 
    0, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

How can I get a summary table like this;

[image]

I thought I could do it by:

```
st_count <- Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x, y, all = TRUE),list(table(df$Math),
                                                               table(df$ELA),
                                                               table(df$PE)))
```

But it did not work as i want. I think i might complicate a simple question. any suggestion?

Comment: How did you come to 4 Students in Math? Shouldn't there be only 3?

Comment: My bad. should be 3 for math

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `stack` + `colSums`

```
> setNames(rev(stack(colSums(df))),c("Subject","Student Count"))
  Subject Student Count
1    Math             4
2     ELA             2
3      PE             3
```

Comment: I just updated my post with new dataset. Could you take a look and see what I could do? How should I handle those extra cols

Comment: @Stataq Is `ID` or `Pass` used to get the desired output?

Comment: nope. as my data contain much more cols. I am not sure how to handle them if I don't want to create a subset for it.

Comment: @Stataq Perhaps `df[-(1:2)]` to replace `df` in my answer?

Comment: This might be a silly question: Can I write the codes like `df[-(1:2] %>% setNames(rev(stack(colSums(.))),c("Subject","Student Count"))` ? Is it a way I can pass it through?

Comment: @Stataq Try `df[-(1:2)] %>%
  colSums() %>%
  stack() %>%
  rev() %>%
  setNames(c("Subject", "Student Count"))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `colSums`:

```
colSums(df[3:5])
#Math  ELA   PE 
#   3    2    3
```

and to come to columns ether `cbind`

```
cbind(colSums(df[3:5]))
#     [,1]
#Math    3
#ELA     2
#PE      3
```

or `stack`

```
stack(colSums(df[3:5]))[2:1]
#   ind values
#1 Math      3
#2  ELA      2
#3   PE      3
```

Alternatively you can use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(values~ind, stack(df[3:5]), sum)
#   ind values
#1 Math      3
#2  ELA      2
#3   PE      3
```

or `xtabs`

```
xtabs(values~ind, stack(df[3:5]))
#ind
#Math  ELA   PE 
#   3    2    3
```

or `sapply`

```
sapply(df[3:5], sum)
#Math  ELA   PE 
#   3    2    3
```

or `apply`

```
apply(df[3:5], 2, sum)
#Math  ELA   PE 
#   3    2    3
```

...

The names can be set by using `setNames` or `names` you have created an object.

Comment: any suggestion on how to make it into a table as I show? Many thanks

Comment: You can try `aggregate`.

Comment: Hi, I am new to `aggregate`.  If the df has more cols which I don't need to sum, how should i take care of that? Do i have to build a subset?

Comment: Yes you have to *subset* your `data.frame`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -ID) %>%
   group_by(Subject = name) %>%
   summarise(Count = sum(value))
```